# tar up a directory including the directory

Tags: directory, tar

I am trying to tar up a directory and include the directory so that the directory is there when untarred because it is used in an pre-written installation script that is out of my control the result has to be only one object (the directory).

Example:

```
tar -czvf filename.tar.gz directory
```

When I look inside the tar file I see:

```
./directory/file1

./directory/file2
```

etc

Yet when I `tar -xvf filename.tar.gz`, the results do not include "directory" meaning what comes out is:

```
./file1

./file2
```

what needs to be the result of the tar -xvf should only be:

```
/directory/
```

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.
Ask instead on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `tar` v1.34-2 the commands you used would work as you want.

I am not familiar with the BSD `tar` but the `man` page doesn't seem to mention any options for that. Maybe try to install the GNU `tar` instead or create a temporary dir to copy your files to (which might be painfully long).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. I looked at the man page as well and didn't see that option either.

I think the only answer is to use the -C option = specifying a directory to put the files in... which in my case mean I have to re-factor someone else's ansible code using the unarchive module. I was hoping not to have to do that.